# loss-of-significance error

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

Reduce loss of significance error in the following equation by re-arranging terms:

$f_1(x) = \frac{1- \cos(x)}{x^2}$ , assuming $x$ is near $0$.

Let $f_2(x)$ be the function rewritten to reduce loss of error.

So far I have obtained

$f_1(x) = \frac{1- \cos(x)}{x^2} \bigg(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\bigg) = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(1+\cos(x))} $

But I'm having difficulty understanding how one would figure out one which steps are reducing error. Apparently the answer is $f_2(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}2 \sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$ but I have don't know why or how that conclusion has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty standard trig identity is $\sin^2(u)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2u)$.  It shouldn't be too hard to find that in a text book or on the internet somewhere.  Let $u=x/2$ and rearrange terms and you get the given expression.  You didn't say that you have a problem understanding how this reduces error, but I'm in an atypically garrulous mood so, the first expression, as x goes to zero, involves two mutually cancelling infinities, $1/x^2$ from the first term and $-1/x^2$ from the leading term of the $\cos()$ expansion.  Re-writing as done here gets rid fo those terms before any division has to take place.

Comment: thanks. that's not really the trouble though. the trouble is that numerically one answer is superior to the other i.e. it returns more significant figures. i don't know how you would determine which function returns more sig-figs

Comment: But that's what bob is saying. In the original form, you are subtracting two large quantities, and that's where you lose significant figures.

Comment: this may be an unrelated request but what would you suggest as a pre-requisite to numerical analysis? i feel that real analysis would be useful to study before numerical analysis. but my school only requires the calculus sequence along with elementary algorithms

Comment: @franklin, better to post this as a new question --- no one will look for it here. My answer would be that the people in the best position to answer this question are the faculty members at your school.

Answer (score 1):

Loss of significant digits is almost always due to subtracting almost equal numbers (for example, $x = 1.01$ and $y = 1.02$ to 3 digits, but $y - x = 0.01$ with 1 digit only). In your example, the problem is that when $x \approx 0$, $\cos x \approx 1$. So you try to get rid of that $1 - \cos x$, here multiplying by $1 + \cos x$. That factor has no problem, is is ${} \approx 2$

Answer (score 0):

From the [sine half-angle formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.21):

$$1-\cos{x} = 2 \sin^2{\left ( \frac{x}{2} \right )}$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the $1-\cos x$ term.  If $x$ is small, this is about $\frac {x^2}2$ from the Taylor series.  But using six place decimal precision, if $x=0.01,\ \ \cos x \approx 0.999500$ Subtracting $1-0.999500=0.000500$ leaves only three places of accuracy.  Using $\frac {x^2}2$ gives full accuracy as there is no cancellation- we know the answer is $0.000500000$.  When you multiplied by $1+ \cos x$ and changed the $1-\cos^2 x$ to $\sin^2 x$ you analytically and exactly did the subtraction and got rid of the cancellation.